# Hilbert Matrix, Gaussian Elimination with varying pivot strategies, and computation error.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

I'm doing a project for my Numerical Analysis class about computational error related to Gaussian elimination, gaussian elimination with partial pivoting, and gaussian elimination with scaled partial pivoting. One exercise is to use each method on a Hilbert Matrix or size n=10 and n=20. In theory, the amount of error should decrease as I go through the methods: GE -> GE+Partial Pivoting -> Ge+Scaled Partial Pivoting, but for the Hilbert matrix the opposite seems to be true. The least error occurs for just normal GE. Have I done something wrong or is this how Hilbert matrices behave?

Comment: The error estimations are exactly that: estimations. They do not exclude the possibility that for some matrices, inequalities are reversed.

Comment: You need to add more information. How is your error defined? Exactly which error are you measuring and which norm are you applying? What is the machine precision? In the case of n=20, the condition number of the Hilbert matrix is so high that you can not possibly solve Ax=b we any hope of success, regardless of which algorithm you are using.